# ngrx/store Can't resolve all parameters for function (state, action)

Tags: angular, .net-core, ngrx-store, ngrx-store-4.0

I am currently attempting to upgrade @ngrx/store in my application but I am getting an error "Can't resolve all parameters for function (state, action)"

My code may be found [here.](https://bitbucket.org/tonywr7/angularreduxtest)

It is a Visual Studio .Net Angular app created using the new Angular templates found in Visual Studio. Prior to upgrading this application, I did have it working with versions: 
"@ngrx/core": "1.2.0",
"@ngrx/effects": "2.0.0",
"@ngrx/store": "2.2.1"

so it is the process of upgrading it to the latest version that has broken the application. Any ideas what I need to do to fix this?

Comment: create a simple demo depicting your problem that would be much better

Comment: as much as I'd like to create a simple demo, I was hopeful that someone with some knowledge of the area would be able to see which step in the upgrade process that I had missed.

Comment: there are a tone of new breaking changes in the new ngrx module , so there has been no safe way to upgrade  just for a start up you can check this link on how to refractor to ngrx 4 [link](https://rahulrsingh09.github.io/AngularConcepts/ngrx)

Comment: Its ok, I managed to get it running. I had to change how it set the reducers in the app.module. I have published my result here: https://github.com/tonywr71/AngularReduxTest